# Populating an array by key and looping it

Tags: javascript, angular

I run the following code inside a loop to fill data for specific `table.$key`:

```
this.tableUsers[table.$key] = userData;
```

I need the `table.$key` index in order to get the user details for each table.

I also want to loop all items in my `this.tableUsers` and output the `userData` of all tables without knowing the `table.$key`

I tried to loop it like that:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of tableUsers">
      test
    </div>
```

but in my console log I noticed this output:

[image]

so I created a pipe to loop keys but it doesn't work:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of tableUsers | keys">
      test
    </div>
```

Keys Pipe:

```
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
```

How I can loop each item as displayed in my console log?

Comment: Can you display a couple of examples of what the objects in that array look like?

Comment: How does it matter? the objects in the array are just objects of user data, username, picture. I need to iterate each object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think to do this is to use two `*ngFor` loops.

Example:

```html
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">
    <div *ngFor="let user of tableUsers[key]">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer `*ngFor` loops over the table keys and the inner `*ngFor` iterates over the users for the current key value.